# Overlay/pause after tikzpicture is not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

In the following example, in the pdf I am not getting any puase after item 1 and before the start of item 2. Any solution will be helpful. Thanks

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]
{author in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center
{title    in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{1em}
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
\vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\usepackage[german]{babel}

% Search online for beamer themes to find your favorite or use 
the     Berkeley theme as in this file.
%\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]


\usepackage{color} % It may be necessary to set PCTeX or 
   whatever       program you are using to output a .pdf instead of a
    .dvi file in order to see color on your screen.
\usepackage{graphicx} % This package is needed if you wish to 
include  external image files.
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
      \theoremstyle{definition} % See Lesson Three of the 
LaTeX Manual  for more on this kind of "proclamation."
\newtheorem*{dfn}{A Reasonable Definition} 

 \begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Intuition: Continued...}
  \tikzstyle{format} = [draw, thin, fill=blue!20]
  \begin{itemize}
     \item<1-> Recall the proof of tracking lemma  
       %\tikzstyle{medium} = [ellipse, draw, thin, 
    fill=green!20, minimum height=2.5em]

     \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex', thick]
      % We need to set at bounding box first. Otherwise the diagram
       % will change position for each frame.
         \path[use as bounding box] (-5,0.5) rectangle (10,-2);
         \path[->]<1-> node[format] (link) {Algorithm};
         \path[->]<2-> node[format, below of=link] (incl) {O.D.E soln.:};
          \end{tikzpicture}

          \item<2->  Solution

             \end{itemize}
               \end{frame}

                \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You second box in the image and your second item both have overlay specification `<2->` meaning that they appear on slide two, and after.  To make the second item turn up a slide after the second image write `\item<3->` instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Intuition: Continued...}
  \tikzstyle{format} = [draw, thin, fill=blue!20]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> Recall the proof of tracking lemma  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex', thick]
      \path[use as bounding box] (-5,0.5) rectangle (10,-2);
      \path[->]<1-> node[format] (link) {Algorithm};
      \path[->]<2-> node[format, below of=link] (incl) {O.D.E soln.:};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \item<3->  Solution
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```